Multiple different forms in a view Django
I was wondering if there was a way to have multiple different forms in a single view and to press a single submit button for the information to be stored.
I have the following forms, the first one is my general form that should be created first:
class GeneralForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ("C","C"),
        ("E","E")
    )

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("A", "A"),
        ("F", "F"),
    )
    type=forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    number=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    TURN_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "1"),
        ("2", "2"),
        ("3", "3")
    )
    turn = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TURN_CHOICES)

   

    class Meta:
        model = models.General
        fields=["name","type","number","turn"]

The second one needs an instance of the first one and so does the third:
class TypeOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    num_chairs=forms.IntegerField()
    num_instalations = forms.IntegerField()
    total = forms.IntegerField()
    num_programs = forms.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        model = models.TypeOne
        fields=["num_chairs","num_instalations","total","billetes_cien"]



class TypeTwoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    num_available_seats=forms.IntegerField()
    num_available_instalations = forms.IntegerField()
    total = forms.IntegerField()
    num_new_programs = forms.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        model = models.TypeTwo
        fields=["num_available_seats", "num_available_instalations","total","num_programs" ]

I was reading I could use FormSets but im not sure if i can use different forms instead of multiple instances of the same form

If all the form inputs are enclosed within <form>...</form> tags in your template, all the data can be sent with a single button.  There are also ways to create a single from using multiple models as shown in this question.  The problem is that the two latter forms are based on information from the first.  That would require AJAX I think, but you'd need to provide info on how the later forms depend on the first to know how.  Formsets would be many of the same form, so probably not the way to go.

thanks, the other two forms have a ForeignKey to General, therefore general should be created before TypeOne and TypeOne. I'm not sure if that anwers your question

You can use get_context_data() for that and put a form in a context, But if you want to fill some fields of the form you need to validate the form.
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    context['general_form'] = GeneralForm()
    return context

Validating like that
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = GeneralForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('general_form'))


I was thinking of doing something like that or using a form set since type one and type two have a ForeignKey to General

i was also wondering, would I have to do that in both type one and type two???

@PerlaDelaO if you have a model with a ForeignKey, Use the default form of Django and create another form for other one its a simple way to have two form in a page.
Also you can authenticate the form in view.
